# How to optimise parameters in a TradingView Pine script?

Tags: back-testing, tradingview-api, pine-script

I want to optimise indicator parameters in a TradingView Pine backtest. This is possible with other tools, but when I search for this functionality in TradingView I don't find anything. Can anybody please help?

If it isn't possible in TradingView, then is there a way of doing it with another tool?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The only way I have found to do this was to make a script that programmatically presses the up/down buttons to change the parameters, checks the backtest results, and moves on to the next param when it has not received better results after a couple presses. I would share the script but unfortunately I lost it on a destroyed computer.

Comment: Leave a feature request with TradingView anywhere you can - GetSatisfaction, Reddit, and of course via their support ticketing system.

Comment: @MikeFurlender manually making change and re-testing all the time consumes a lot of time

Answer (score 4):

There is a TSLab software package that is designed to create trading robots.
The kit has an intuitive interface for writing trading strategies,  it allows you to automate optimisation the selection of parameters for running strategies using historical data.

The program is free if you do not need to run the robot for real trading. Automatic optimisation of parameters for strategies will be available without restrictions.

Comment: How can we run pine-script code on top of TSLab datasets?

Comment: @alper, no way (or at least I do not know of such possibilities). In TSLab, you need to create a similar script.

Answer (score 0):

Not available now for version 4, I believe. Using AutoIt or similar software is just a temporary but inefficient solution.

Answer (score -1):

TradingView Strategy Finder (1.1.5)
It´s a chrome plug in, and it does what you need.